# Why am I getting a KeyError when reading an ini file with Python's configparser?

Tags: python, ini, configparser

I would like to connect to the database in Python.
My code:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
import pymysql as mysql

class DatabaseG:
    def __init__(self):
        config = ConfigParser()
        config.read("config.ini")
        self.connection = mysql.connect(
                user=config["books"]["user"],
                passwd=config["books"]["password"],
                host=config["books"]["host"],
                db=config["books"]["database"],
        )
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        query = """
                CREATE TABLE BOOKS (book_url TEXT, book_id)
                """

        self.cursor.execute(query)

db = DatabaseG()
```

My config.ini looks like this:

```
[books]
user=myuser
password=mypass
host=blabla.cz
database=
```

But I got an error `KeyError: 'user'`. What does it mean? The user does not exist?

Whole Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 259, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 205, in main
  File "/home/vojtam/Desktop/mydb/db.py", line 25, in __init__
    user=config["books"]["user"],
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/configparser.py", line 960, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'user'
```

Comment: Include the whole traceback you're getting.

Comment: You're missing the section in your config query. Try `config['books']['user']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to access the `books` section first from the config:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
import pymysql as mysql

class DatabaseG:
    def __init__(self):
        config = ConfigParser()
        config.read("config.ini")
        books_config = config["books"]
        self.connection = mysql.connect(
                user=books_config["user"],
                passwd=books_config["password"],
                host=books_config["host"],
                db=books_config["database"],
        )
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        query = """
                CREATE TABLE BOOKS (book_url TEXT, book_id)
                """

        self.cursor.execute(query)

db = DatabaseG()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it did not help. See my edit, please

Comment: @vojta No, that error is not possible with this code. Run your code again.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to update the Traceback

Comment: @vojta Are you use that the `config.ini` looks exactly like that?

Comment: Yes, database variable is empty. Could that be a problem?

Comment: @vojta No, it should not hurt.

Comment: @vojta Did you solve the issue?

Comment: yes, using your solution and given the fakt that I had a missclick in my user